# Windows 7; select multiple files, only opens one

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Whenever I am in Explorer and try to open multiple files (of the same extension and type) it only opens one. The process is as follows:

1. Select top file
2. Shift
3. Click last file
4. File > Open

Only the last file opens. Any help?

P.S. The files are Word .doc files from Microsoft Office pre 2007 however I am currently in Microsoft 2010

Comment: How many documents are you trying to open at once?

Comment: It doesn't matter how many, it can vary between 2 to 15 to 17...

Answer (score 2):

Try pressing the <kbd>Return</kbd> key instead of doing `File -> Open`.

This should initiate an open action on each selected item. I'm not sure why `File -> Open` isn't serving that purpose, or if it should in the first place,  but if using the <kbd>Return</kbd> key does not, then the issue is with Word, in which case you might try opening word, selecting all of the files in Windows Explorer, and then just dragging them into Word.

Comment: well I tried your suggestions. 
First, selecting them all and pushing ENTER/RETURN did not work. So I tried the second option. However, although it did open all of them and in order the issue was this : It only opened up the first page of every document AND it combined all the documents into ONE BIG Document. So in the end all it was one long document of nothing but Cover Pages. @_@ Help?